# Is there a reason for the "small" record with $5$ prime factors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, carmichael-numbers

Mathworld gives a survey over the number of digits of the record Carmichaelnumbers with $3,4,5,6$ prime factors [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelNumber.html)

> Is there a reason that with $5$ prime factors , the record is much smaller than with $4$ or $6$ prime factors ? Or is this a typo ?

Many constructions of huge Carmichaelnumbers are based on expression having simultaneously to be prime. But why is then the record for $6$ factors much higher ?

Comment: Could be that to have 5 factors you need to be a 4th power of a prime?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Carmichael numbers must be squarefree. Also, with a 4th power , the construction should be easier rather than more difficult.

Comment: Read it wrong read it as 5 factors not 5 prime factors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The survey you linked is out of date.

Unfortunately there seems to be no updated database for this purpose.
However you can find some new record Carmichael numbers, published once in a while at [listserv.nodak.edu](https://listserv.nodak.edu/) or [mersenneforum.org](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=28643)

Referring to your question, J.N. Muñoz found a [5-Carmichael number with 14241 digits](https://listserv.nodak.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=ind1508&L=NMBRTHRY&P=R329&1=NMBRTHRY&9=A&J=on&d=No%20Match%3BMatch%3BMatches&z=4) in 2015.

Comment: Even if outdated , the about 1k digit number surely was no record at that time.